# UIView's frame rendering larger than frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to add a subview to a UIScrollView. First I instantiate the view controller from the storyboard, then set the view's frame to the application bounds. When I add the view to the UIScrollView, it is clearly larger than it's supposed to be.

```
CGRect mainFrame = CGRectMake(0, topButtonHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight);

feelingVC = (FeelingViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"feelingVC"];
feelingVC.delegate = self;
feelingView = feelingVC.view;
[feelingView setFrame:mainFrame];
[self.scrollView addSubview:feelingView];
```

I can tell because its background color is extending past where it should be. "Debug View Hierarchy" mode in XCode also confirms this. But, if I inspect the view's frame, it prints out what it should be, not what it actually is.

A view of the same size, but generated completely programatically, works as it should:

```
mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainFrame];
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.scrollView addSubview:mainView];
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this issue - I've instantiated other views from their view controllers, also via the storyboard, and set their frames without any problems.

*EDIT*: This is being called from viewDidLoad of the view controller containing the UIScrollView. screenWidth & screenHeight are calculated as such (they are instance variables):

```
screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width;
screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height;
```

Comment: What function does this code get called from? How are screenWidth and screenHeight defined?

Comment: Gets called in viewDidLoad of the view controller with the scrollView.

Comment: This may or may not be related to your issue, but viewDidLoad is often a wonky place to set screen/size related properties, especially if using auto layout. viewDidLayoutSubviews is often better.

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to set the view frame in `viewWillAppear` method.

`viewDidLoad` is not a good place to set frames (because it called only once when view getting loaded.), the UI components are not properly configured by the system yet.

Also, prefer to use:

```
screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
```

instead of

```
screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width;
screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height;
```

since bounds has correct positional information taking into consideration the device's orientation in this case.

Or you can just do this, after initializing the mainView inside `viewDidLoad:` Method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    mainView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
}
```

you can also add this to reconfigure the view frame whenever the subviews are updated:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews { //or viewDidLayoutSubviews
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    mainView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
}
```